# Interpretation of root mean square

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

Can somebody please explain what is the significance of root mean square when we consider a set of data(any type of data). I have seen its usage in RMS value of voltage or let us say RMS velocity in the kinetic theory of gases. I would like to know what's its significance over other parameters such as mean, standard deviation, etc.

Thank you

Comment: The standard deviation is the *root mean square* of the difference from the mean, i.e. the square root of the average of the square of the difference, while the basic *root mean square* is the difference from $0$; with something like alternating current the mean is likely to be $0$ so there is essentially no difference.

Comment: @Henry Thank You.